# What is wrong with my root mean square average?

Tags: python, loops

I've been working on this code that calculates the room mean square average. Something seems to be wrong with my loop structure, can anyone help find my mistake? thanks!

```
def rms():
    print("This program will calculate the RMS of your values.")
    print()
    n = int(input("Please enter the number of values you want 
    calculated: "))
    total = 0.0
for i in range(n):
    x = float(input("Enter a desired values:"))
    total = total + math.sqrt(x)



print("\nThe Root Mean Square is:", math.sqrt(total/n))
```

Comment: _`Something seems to be wrong`_. The wrong thing is indentation. Please fix it first.

Comment: It looks like you're dividing the current total by `n` every loop, are you sure that's what you want?  Try writing down the mathematical/logical steps you want to do. If you find you divide by `n` only at the end, then you should amend your code to reflect that.

Comment: Hint: the mathematical operation is called root-mean-*square*, not root-mean-*square-root*...

Comment: sum all squares of x  (x*x) - after all are summed divide by N and it draw its root - iirc

Comment: Are you sure you fixed the indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an wrong which is in there `total = total + math.sqrt(x)` the wrong is that you should find the **squared x** Not **square root of x** so try my fixed code:-

```
def rms():
    print("This program will calculate the RMS of your values.\n")
    n = int(input("Please enter the number of values you want calculated: "))
    total = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        x = float(input("Enter a desired values:"))
        total += x ** 2 #it means x powered by two

    print("\nThe Root Mean Square is:", math.sqrt(total/n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I see you wanted this all in `rms()` from reading I believe you wanted everything in `rms()` be careful with your indentations so parts of your function do not fall outside of the funciton, this works though, not sure your desired output though.

```
import math

def rms():
    print("This program will calculate the RMS of your values.")
    print()
    n = int(input("Please enter the number of values you want calculated: "))
    total = 0.0 
    for i in range(n):
        x = float(input("Enter a desired values:"))
        total = total + math.sqrt(x)
    print("\nThe Root Mean Square is:", math.sqrt(total/n))

rms()
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 rms.py 
> This program will calculate the RMS of your values.
>
> Please enter the number of values you want calculated: 3
> Enter a desired values:10
> Enter a desired values:3
> Enter a desired values:2
>
> The Root Mean Square is: 1.4501197686295146
> ```

Answer (score -1):

If I infer correctly then you want to take each input, square it, average the sum and square root that sum. Remember that when averaging (finding mean), only divide by the sum at the end:

```
def rms():
    total = 0.0
    count = 0
    while True:
        x = input('enter value (enter nothing to stop):')
        if x.strip() == '':
            break
        count += 1
        total += float(x) ** 2

    print('mean square root is:', math.sqrt(total/count))
    # return math.sqrt(total / count)
```